# Achieving 1Gb/s using PCI (not express) NIC

Tags: lan, bandwidth, pci

I am using an old PC (Phenom II x940, 3GB of ram) as a NAS. The motherboard's build-in NIC was only 100 mib/s so I bought a used Intel Pro/1000 GT (connected via PCI (!) - not PCIe) to achieve better speeds over local network.

I have been testing my setup with both iperf3 and using file transfer (SMB and NFS). My results are varying between 850 Mib/s using iperf3 and 50 MB/s transferring files using SMB and around 30 MB/s with NFS.

The server is running on Alpine Linux 3.18 using OpenZFS.

Before I've bought the NIC I was achieving approximately full theoretical bandwidth (~10 MB/s) while transferring files over SMB so I was expecting ~100 MB/s read/write.

Is there anything I can do to improve my setup and hence achieve better speed over lan?

I am using a switch with 5x1Gb ports so this should not be a bottleneck.

Comment: What other devices do you have on the same bus? Are you sure it's the PCI bus that is the problem, and not the system's CPU? What does iperf3 reach when tested against localhost?

Comment: @user1686 There are no other devices using either PCI or PCIe. When testing using iperf3 against localhost (iperf3 -c localhost) I get 3.5 Gb/s . I have underclocked the CPU to check if its speed impacts the NIC performance and it does not. Lowering the multiplier to 5x (so to my understanding, CPU max speed is limited to 1Ghz per core) I get exactly the same results using iperf3.

Comment: The PCI should be fast enough. I would guess that the bottleneck is your disk, if it's for example IDE (ATA 100).

Comment: there will always be overhead, so bear in mind that 1Gb exactly may not be plausible and 10MB/s is about 80% of 100Mbit. Also, older HDDs may cap at 60MB/s or less.

Comment: @harrymc All of the hdds are connected to sata ports. What bothers me is that when testing write speed using dd (1G file from /dev/zero) it takes ~12+ seconds to write it on zfs pool while only half of it on system partition (I don't remeber what file system Alpine linux is using but assume something like ext2).

Comment: Testing against _localhost_ is very different from testing with actual hardware, because it just involves copying memory in kernel space. It is very much not comparable. // 850 MBit/s is a good result and shows your bottleneck is elsewhere. // Not sure why you argue that because your PC could service 100 MBit/s it should be able to service 1000 MBit/s. Care to expand on that? (Please add all clarifications to your question!)

Comment: My experience using old commodity PCs as fileservers and soho-grade switches indicates that 50MB/s is about what you should expect from gigabit. I've only been able to do faster using pre-built NAS's or enterprise kit like SANs and hardware RAID. Also note that a home netgear (or whatever) 1GB switches won't have sufficient umph to provide Gb bandwidth to multiple ports simultaneously. keep in mind your max bandwidth will be based on two ports on the same switch operating at more or less equal speed.

Comment: wondering if the file transfer numbers are using the file bytes rather than the actual  transmission bytes. My guess is yes and that would skew the calculation low.